# Upgrading to Windows 10 Pro from Windows 7 Pro and migrating hdd to ssd

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ssd

I'm upgrading to Windows 10 Pro from Windows 7 Pro and migrating my hdd to ssd.

Which should I do first.

1. The hdd has 221GB free out of 465GB.
2. The ssd is 1TB.
3. And I have a 2TB USB external drive.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your question is?  All you should have to do is clone the HDD to the SDD then perform the upgrade to Windows 10.  Are you stuck on specific step?

Comment: I'm asking which task to perform first. OS upgrade or system clone.

Comment: @ChuckO Usually doesn't matter but knowing how fast SSDs are comparatively, the order becomes really obvious.